# Retrieve missing column Values

Tags: mysql, sql, highcharts

I am trying to plot graph using **Highcharts** in Yii2. I have a table **student_detail** having columns like **year, height, province_id** and another table **province**.

I want to retrieve rows having average heights of all the provinces year-wise. I want to get a zero value when there are no rows for an year in student_detail table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT year FROM student_detail ORDER BY year
```

returns:

```
2000 
2001
2009 
2012
2013
2014
2015
```

And the query:

```
SELECT temp.name AS name, GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(temp.height,0)) AS DATA, GROUP_CONCAT(year) AS years FROM ( SELECT sd.year AS year, p.name AS NAME, FLOOR(AVG(sd.height)) AS height FROM student_detail sd, province p WHERE sd.province_id = p.id GROUP BY sd.year, p.name HAVING sd.year IN (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM student_detail ORDER BY year) ORDER BY sd.year ) AS temp GROUP BY name
```

returns:

```
name     data           years
KPK      58,60,58,56    2001,2015,2009,2000
Punjab   90,78,90       2014,2012,2013
```

I want data (to be shown as 0 ) for the missing years for KP and Punjab.

Comment: You are going to need a `years` table.  Then you can use an `outer join` to return the null data values.

Comment: I posted a solution.  You also need to use a `cross join` to get those values.  Take a look at the fiddle I created and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

To get missing years, you are going to need to introduce a `years` table. Then you can use a `cross join` to create a `cartesian product` between the years and the provinces.  Finally you can use an `outer join` to get the data requested:

```
SELECT temp.name AS name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(temp.height,0) order by year) AS DATA, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(year order by year) AS years 
FROM ( SELECT years.year AS year, p.name AS NAME, FLOOR(AVG(sd.height)) AS height 
      FROM (
        select 2010 year union all select 2011 union all select 2012
        union all select 2013 year union all select 2014 union all select 2015
        ) years 
      cross join province p
      left join student_detail sd on years.year = sd.year and sd.province_id = p.id 
      GROUP BY years.year, p.name 
      ORDER BY years.year ) 
      AS temp 
GROUP BY name
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f10c/1)

Comment: You are a rockstar :) I edited your query i.e. the years derived table with SELECT DISTINCT year FROM student_detail ORDER BY year                              and it worked :)